# Generate link to external website using a javascript function in angular app

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a angular application. In the index.html, I have header with some links to external website.

```
<a href="#" onclick="getUrl('about.html');">click here </a>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getUrl(link)
    {
        return "https://external-domain.com/"+link;
    }
</script>
```

but this does not give me desired result as my angular application redirects to localhost:4200
I don't know why?

Comment: there are a few smells here: why do you put it in index.html? Why include a script tag, if you got angular components to do that for you. Consider creating a header component for your header, and handling the stuff there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update **getUrl** function as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getUrl(link)
    {
    window.location.href = "https://external-domain.com/"+link;
       
    }
</script>
```

When you will click on the "*click here*" link it will redirect you to external website successfully.